# Implementing Interface using extension methods in c#

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I have an Interface:

```
public interface IMessager
{
    void ShowMessage();
}
```

Is there any way to implement this interface using extension methods?

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static void ShowMessage(this MyClass e)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Extension");
  }
}
```

and a class that implement it:

```
public class MyClass:IMessager
{
    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        ShowMessage(); // I expect that program write "Extension" in console
    }
}
```

But when I run the program I get the `System.StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you posted is just a method calling itself recursively (hence the `StackOverflowException`).

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish but to answer your question

> Is there any way to implement this interface using extension methods?

No.

To be a bit more pragmatic about this though, if your aim is to only write your method once you have a few options:

#### 1. Call the extension explicitly

```
public class MyClass:IMessager
{
    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        Extensions.ShowMessage(this);
    }
}
```

although as pointed out in comments, this basically defeats the point of using the extension method. Additionally there is still "boiler-plate code" such that every time you implement your interface you have to call the static method from within the method (not very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

#### 2. Use an abstract class instead of an interface

```
public abstract class MessengerBase
{
    public void ShowMethod() { /* implement */ }
}

public class MyClass : MessengerBase {}

...

new MyClass().ShowMethod();
```

This issue with this though is that you can't inherit from multiple classes.

#### 3. Use extension on the interface

```
public interface IMessenger { /* nothing special here */ }

public class MyClass : IMessenger { /* also nothing special */ }

public static class MessengerExtensions
{
    public static void ShowMessage(this IMessenger messenger)
    {
        // implement
    }
}

...

new MyClass().ShowMessage();
```

Comment: Which of course partially defeats the point of the syntax of extension methods